# is there a TCP version to do slow start from a certain threshold?

Tags: tcp

I'm using a messaging library for transferring data in a virtual networks topology. In fact, I send messages using client/server architecture, but the slow start phase of TCP protocol influence the throughput of transferring data.
My question is : is there a version of TCP where we can make a slow start differently ? I mean if we can impose the threshold of slow start ?
Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Comment: This is actually depends on your OS, but many operation systems allows you to tune or ever change flow control algorithms. For your needs might be more appropriative something like [HSTCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSTCP) or [CUBIC TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUBIC_TCP). Also you can try to change  initial congestion window `initcwd`. If you on linux also read [man tcp](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp), it have many configurable parameters.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response @slava-bacherikov , I will see how to integrate HSTCP or CUBIC TCP in my program.

Comment: Those congestion control algorithms should be changed on OS level, not on application level. For example on linux you can change it to [H-TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-TCP) via ` cat htcp > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control `

Comment: Thanks @slava-bacherikov , in fact I want to control the slow start of TCP protocol because it decreases the throughput that I get when I'm transferring small message (<=10 Mo). I don't want to modify the algorithm of congestion that TCP implements but I wondered if there is a version in TCP when we can do slow start in different way.